NestJS inject multiple values into same service
Working on NestJS app and faced situation I cannot find answer in docs.
I have set of services, Kafka connection and base consumer implementation. Consumer implemented as
export abstract class KafkaConsumerBaseService<
  TParsedMessage extends KafkaMessage,
> implements OnModuleInit {
  protected readonly redisService: RedisService;
  protected readonly kafkaService!: KafkaService;
  protected readonly logger!: CustomeLogger;

  constructor(topic: KafkaTopicType, cls: Constructable<TParsedMessage>) {
    this.topic = topic;
    this.cls = cls
  }  
}


where cls is actually a DTO to validate Kafka message. And as it is implemented in OOp approach I have to inject (they are all injectable) RedisService, KafkaService and CustomerLogger in children, who inherits this base consumer service and, mot important - implemets process method that called once message validated. One app can have multiple consumers (for instance one has 8), so I implement it like
export class Consumer1 extends KafkaConsumerBaseService<DTO_1> {
  protected readonly logger: CustomLogger = new CustomLogger(
    Consumer1.name,
  );

  constructor (
    protected readonly consumer1Service Consumer1Service,
    protected readonly kafkaService: KafkaService,
    protected readonly redisService: RedisService,
  ) {
    super('topic1', DTO_1);
  }
}

export class Consumer2 extends KafkaConsumerBaseService<DTO_2> {
  protected readonly logger: CustomLogger = new CustomLogger(
    Consumer2.name,
  );

  constructor (
    protected readonly consumer1Service Consumer2Service,
    protected readonly kafkaService: KafkaService,
    protected readonly redisService: RedisService,
  ) {
    super('topic2', DTO_2);
  }
}

export class Consumer3 extends KafkaConsumerBaseService<DTO_3> {
  protected readonly logger: CustomLogger = new CustomLogger(
    Consumer3.name,
  );

  constructor (
    protected readonly consumer3Service Consumer3Service,
    protected readonly kafkaService: KafkaService,
    protected readonly redisService: RedisService,
  ) {
    super('topic3', DTO_3);
  }
}

....

After all all these consumers are imported in the app.module.
I'd like to get rid of injecting logger (but it actually depends on specific service name) and RedisService + KafkaService. At least latter 2.
But how to inject different params and instantiate services without using it in another servicesm just to provide and use?
